# Php script for updating text woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have this php script that updates my product titles:

```
add_filter( 'the_title', 'change_product_title', 10, 2 );
function change_product_title( $title, $id ) {
$Find = 'Mens Watch';
$ReplaceWith = 'Herreur';


//REMOVE DESIRED STRING FROM PRODUCT TITLE
$title = str_replace($Find, $ReplaceWith, $title);

return $title;
}
```

And it updates the title in every product title. But how can I make it so every word that has $find = ?? Gets replaced? And also, how can I add more words to the script so they also are replaced on my site?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
add_filter( 'gettext', 'wp_custom_translate_text', 10, 3 );


function wp_custom_translate_text($translated_text, $untranslated_text, $domain) {

        $find = array("sample", "book");
        $replace = array("test");

        $translated_text = str_replace($find, $replace, $translated_text);
    
    return $translated_text;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Could it be modified so not only the product-title is updated with the new word? So every word on my site is replaced. And I want to update lets say "color" to "farve" or "glasses" to "glas", it that possible to? So I can update mulitple words, with individual words.

Comment: try modified snippet

Comment: No, it does not work. Looks like there is missing a opening "{", but where should it be placed? Again thank you, for your help!

Comment: Still nothing, it does not update the text on my site.